# Certificate Request and the certificate available in store not matching

Tags: certificate, wireshark, tls, x509, client-certificate

I am trying to connect to a third party API which have a mutual TLS authentication setup enabled. So I am supposed to install my client certificates inside my key store and send it on TLS handshake process. I have done the certification installation now and the server certificate request is like this

[image]

And my certificate properties are this

[image]
[image]

[image]

And when I try to connect I get an error like this on Schannel

> The remote server has requested TLS client authentication, but no suitable client certificate could be found. An anonymous connection will be attempted. This TLS connection request may succeed or fail, depending on the server's policy settings.

So my guess is that the request and the certificate available are not matching. Can anyone pls point out which property on certificate is not matching with the request?

CertUtility provideds this result, When I run it agaimst the pfx file I have

```
   ================ Certificate 0 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 0:
Serial Number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
 NotBefore: 12-02-2014 05:30
 NotAfter: 12-02-2029 05:29
Subject: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
No key provider information
Cannot find the certificate and private key for decryption.

================ Certificate 1 ================
================ Begin Nesting Level 1 ================
Element 1:
Serial Number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Issuer: CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA, O=COMODO CA Limited, L=Salford, S=Greater Manchester, C=GB
 NotBefore: 16-02-2018 05:30
 NotAfter: 12-12-2018 05:29
Subject: CN=www.domain.com, OU=PositiveSSL, OU=Domain Control Validated
Non-root Certificate
Cert Hash(sha1): xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
----------------  End Nesting Level 1  ----------------
  Provider = Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Encryption test passed
CertUtil: -dump command completed successfully.
```

> Note: I have two certificates inside this PFX, First is the Intermediary cert and the second is actual cert.

Comment: That's a server certificate.  Look at the Enhanced Key Usage extension.

Comment: @garethTheRed this is the full value of EKU Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)
So I assume it can be used as client certificate too. Sorry for the bad screenshot

Comment: It might be better if you save a local copy of the cert, then run `certutil <file>` against it.  Paste the output into your question after deleting things like signature and public key to save space.  You have saved it to the user's keystore (`certmgr.msc`) as opposed to the machine keystore haven't you?

Comment: @garethTheRed I have updated my question with the data you asked, And I have tried both Current user and local machine stores before (Actually I am working on this same issue for past 10 days :( , Both gives same error as explained in the question